# Simple Cropper event binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, crop

I'm trying to use an image upload/cropping plugin [simple cropper](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Client-Side-Image-Cropping-Plugin-with-Canvas-CSS3-SimpleCropper.html). I have it working fine but I'm dynamically inserting elements with the class `.cropme` that aren't getting the event binding. I've changed most of the click events to use `.on()` instead of `.click()`. Is there something I'm missing?

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.simpleCropper = function () {

var image_dimension_x = 600;
var image_dimension_y = 600;
var scaled_width = 0;
var scaled_height = 0;
var x1 = 0;
var y1 = 0;
var x2 = 0;
var y2 = 0;
var current_image = null;
var aspX = 1;
var aspY = 1;
var file_display_area = null;
var ias = null;
var jcrop_api;
var bottom_html = "<input type='file' id='fileInput' name='files[]'/><canvas id='myCanvas' style='display:none;'></canvas><div id='modal'></div><div id='preview'><div class='buttons'><div class='cancel'></div><div class='ok'></div></div></div>";
$('body').append(bottom_html);

//add click to element
this.on('click', function () {
  aspX = $(this).width();
  aspY = $(this).height();
  file_display_area = $(this);
  $('#fileInput').click();
});

$(document).on('ready', function () {
  //capture selected filename
  $('#fileInput').on('change', function (click) {
    imageUpload($('#preview').get(0));
    // Reset input value
    $(this).val("");
  });

  //ok listener
  $('.ok').on('click', function () {
    preview();
    $('#preview').delay(100).hide();
    $('#modal').hide();
    jcrop_api.destroy();
    reset();
  });

  //cancel listener
  $('.cancel').on('click', function (event) {
    $('#preview').delay(100).hide();
    $('#modal').hide();
    jcrop_api.destroy();
    reset();
  });
});

function reset() {
  scaled_width = 0;
  scaled_height = 0;
  x1 = 0;
  y1 = 0;
  x2 = 0;
  y2 = 0;
  current_image = null;
  aspX = 1;
  aspY = 1;
  file_display_area = null;
}

function imageUpload(dropbox) {
  var file = $("#fileInput").get(0).files[0];
  //var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];
  var imageType = /image.*/;

  if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      // Clear the current image.
      $('#photo').remove();

      // Create a new image with image crop functionality
      current_image = new Image();
      current_image.src = reader.result;
      current_image.id = "photo";
      current_image.style['maxWidth'] = image_dimension_x + 'px';
      current_image.style['maxHeight'] = image_dimension_y + 'px';
      current_image.onload = function () {
        // Calculate scaled image dimensions
        if (current_image.width > image_dimension_x || current_image.height > image_dimension_y) {
          if (current_image.width > current_image.height) {
            scaled_width = image_dimension_x;
            scaled_height = image_dimension_x * current_image.height / current_image.width;
          }
          if (current_image.width < current_image.height) {
            scaled_height = image_dimension_y;
            scaled_width = image_dimension_y * current_image.width / current_image.height;
          }
          if (current_image.width == current_image.height) {
            scaled_width = image_dimension_x;
            scaled_height = image_dimension_y;
          }
        }
        else {
          scaled_width = current_image.width;
          scaled_height = current_image.height;
        }


        // Position the modal div to the center of the screen
        $('#modal').css('display', 'block');
        var window_width = $(window).width() / 2 - scaled_width / 2 + "px";
        var window_height = $(window).height() / 2 - scaled_height / 2 + "px";

        // Show image in modal view
        $("#preview").css("top", window_height);
        $("#preview").css("left", window_width);
        $('#preview').show(500);


        // Calculate selection rect
        var selection_width = 0;
        var selection_height = 0;

        var max_x = Math.floor(scaled_height * aspX / aspY);
        var max_y = Math.floor(scaled_width * aspY / aspX);


        if (max_x > scaled_width) {
          selection_width = scaled_width;
          selection_height = max_y;
        }
        else {
          selection_width = max_x;
          selection_height = scaled_height;
        }

        ias = $(this).Jcrop({
          onSelect: showCoords,
          onChange: showCoords,
          bgColor: '#747474',
          bgOpacity: .4,
          aspectRatio: aspX / aspY,
          setSelect: [0, 0, selection_width, selection_height]
        }, function () {
            jcrop_api = this;
          });
      };

      // Add image to dropbox element
      dropbox.appendChild(current_image);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  } else {
    dropbox.innerHTML = "File not supported!";
  }
}

function showCoords(c) {
  x1 = c.x;
  y1 = c.y;
  x2 = c.x2;
  y2 = c.y2;
}

function preview() {
  // Set canvas
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // Delete previous image on canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Set selection width and height
  var sw = x2 - x1;
  var sh = y2 - y1;


  // Set image original width and height
  var imgWidth = current_image.naturalWidth;
  var imgHeight = current_image.naturalHeight;

  // Set selection koeficient
  var kw = imgWidth / $("#preview").width();
  var kh = imgHeight / $("#preview").height();

  // Set canvas width and height and draw selection on it
  canvas.width = aspX;
  canvas.height = aspY;
  context.drawImage(current_image,(x1 * kw),(y1 * kh),(sw * kw),(sh * kh), 0, 0, aspX, aspY);

  // Convert canvas image to normal img
  var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
  var imageFoo = document.createElement('img');
  imageFoo.src = dataUrl;

  // Append it to the body element
  $('#preview').delay(100).hide();
  $('#modal').hide();
  file_display_area.html('');
  file_display_area.append(imageFoo);

}

$(window).resize(function () {
  // Position the modal div to the center of the screen
  var window_width = $(window).width() / 2 - scaled_width / 2 + "px";
  var window_height = $(window).height() / 2 - scaled_height / 2 + "px";

  // Show image in modal view
      $("#preview").css("top", window_height);
      $("#preview").css("left", window_width);
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to clean my code up but this is what I changed to make this work:

```
this.on('click', function () {
  aspX = $(this).width();
  aspY = $(this).height();
  file_display_area = $(this);
  $('#fileInput').click();
});
```

to

```
$('body').on('click', '.cropme', function () {
  aspX = $(this).width();
  aspY = $(this).height();
  file_display_area = $(this);
  $('#fileInput').click();
});
```